# time display in clock with xy scatter plot in r

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I would like to create the following type of plot. But do not know if there is any package already exists, as I could not find one.
Data:

```
myd <- data.frame (X = 1:5, Y = c(0.8, 0.6, 0.7, 0.75,  0.1), 
     clockd = c(12.05, 12.25, 12.45, 1.30, 2.1))
```

clockd are time 12.05 is 12 Oclock past minutes. I do not know appropriate unit to enter time in R.

```
plot (myd$X, myd$Y)
```

**Edit:** 
The red and green arrow represents the hour and minitue position of clock arms in a clock. 
[image]

Comment: Maybe you can explain what the length of the arrows is supposed to represent. I'm guessing X and Y represent the position of the clock in your plot?

Comment: Maybe you could adapt this piece of code? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877379/how-to-draw-clock-in-r

Comment: @plannapus X and Y is position of clock in the field while the arrow represent hour and minute arm of a clock

Comment: I understood that the blue arrow is the hour and the red the minute but quite obviously in your plot, their length differ from one clock to the other: is it meaningful?

Comment: @plannapus no just hand drawn may not be perfect and long is minutes and short is hour

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
clockplot<-function(x, y, h, m, r, border="black", col="lightblue", 
                    col.hour="darkblue", col.min="red"){
#x and y are the coordinates of the clock
#h and m the hour (base 12) and minutes
# r the radius of the clock
    t<-seq(0,2*pi,by=0.01)
    x.c<-r*cos(t)+x
    y.c<-r*sin(t)+y

    t.h<-pi/2 - 2*pi*(h-m/60)/12
    x.h<-0.5*r*cos(t.h)+x
    y.h<-0.5*r*sin(t.h)+y

    t.m<-pi/2 - 2*pi*m/60
    x.m<-r*cos(t.m)+x
    y.m<-r*sin(t.m)+y

    polygon(x.c,y.c,col=col, border=border)
    segments(x,y,x.h,y.h,col=col.hour)
    segments(x,y,x.m,y.m,col=col.min)
    }

myd <- data.frame (X = 1:5, Y = c(0.8, 0.6, 0.7, 0.75,  0.1), 
                   clockd = c(12.05, 12.25, 12.45, 1.30, 2.1))
myd$hour<-myd$clockd%/%1
myd$min<-myd$clockd%%1 *100

plot(myd$X, myd$Y, type="l", asp=1)
apply(myd,1,function(x)clockplot(x[1],x[2],x[4],x[5], r=0.25))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I'm using suggestion by @GregSnow here with `my.symbols` function from `TeachingDemo` package. This way you can do it with a small(ish) chunk of code but you can have quite big control over the graphical parametrs like size and fill of clock circles, look of arrows, the way you customize your plot, etc. For calculating location of arrows I modified @agstudy code so that it extracts minutes correctly.

```
myd <- data.frame (X = 1:5, Y = c(0.8, 0.6, 0.7, 0.75,  0.1), 
                   clockd = c(12.05, 12.25, 12.45, 1.30, 2.1))
hour <- round(myd$clockd)#takes hours by ignoring decimals
minute <- 100*(myd$clockd - trunc(myd$clockd,2))#takes decimals
#for getting the angle I'm subtracting from pi/2
#thats because pi/2 orients the arrow into 0 degree position, pointing up 
hourAngle <- pi/2 - (hour/12*2*pi)
minuteAngle <- pi/2 - (minute/60*2*pi)
#now all the plotting
plot(myd$X, myd$Y, type="l", xaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="", 
     xlim=c(0.5,5.5), ylim=c(0,1), col="gray")#standard plot, no x axis
axis(1, at=myd$X, labels=myd$X)#custom x-axis
require(TeachingDemo)
my.symbols(myd$X, myd$Y, ms.arrows, angle=hourAngle, add=T, 
           col="blue", symb.plots=TRUE, adj=0)
my.symbols(myd$X, myd$Y, ms.arrows, angle=minuteAngle, add=T, 
           col="red", symb.plots=TRUE, adj=0)
my.symbols(myd$X, myd$Y, ms.polygon, n=250, add=T, 
           r=1.1, col="gray")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Giving your data :

```
read.table(text = 'col1 col2
           0012 0001245',head=T,colClasses=c('character','numeric'))


myd <- data.frame (X = 1:5, 
                   Y = c(0.8, 0.6, 0.7, 0.75,  0.1), 
                   clockd = c(12.05, 12.25, 12.45, 1.30, 2.1))
```

Using lattice+grid we can do somethink like this :

```
library(lattice)
library(grid)
xyplot(Y~X,data=myd,
       panel=function(x,y,...)
       {

         panel.fill(col='yellow')
         panel.lines(x,y)

         h_min <- do.call(rbind,strsplit(as.character(myd$clockd),'[.]'))
         hours <- as.numeric(h_min[,1])
         minutes <- as.numeric(h_min[,2])
         lapply(seq_along(x),
                         function(i)drawClock(x[i],y[i],hour = hours[i], minute = minutes[i]))


       })
```

Where drawClock  is adopted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877379/how-to-draw-clock-in-r)  and trsnformed to the need of this question:

```
drawClock <- function(x0,y0,hour, minute) {
  t <- seq(0, 2*pi, length=13)[-13]
  x <- cos(t)
  y <- sin(t)
  # Circle with ticks
  grid.circle(x=x0, y=y0, default="native", 
              r=unit(0.4,'in'),gp=gpar(fill='blue',alpha=0.5))
  #         grid.segments(x, y, x*.9, y*.9, default="native")
  # Hour hand
  hourAngle <- pi/2 - (hour + minute/60)/12*2*pi
  grid.segments(x0, y0, 
                x0+.06*cos(hourAngle), y0+.06*sin(hourAngle), 
                default="native", gp=gpar(lex=4))
  # Minute hand
  minuteAngle <- pi/2 - (minute)/60*2*pi
  grid.segments(x0, y0, 
                x0+.08*cos(minuteAngle), y0+.08*sin(minuteAngle), 
                default="native", gp=gpar(lex=2))    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `my.symbols` function in the TeachingDemos package for tools to help create this type of plot.