# Clock-like diagramme in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, time

I would like to illustrate associations between a variable and time in R. The data are in the form `y=response` and `x=time` - and I can obviously use `plot` or `ggplot` - but I would like to plot the data in a circular diagramme, ideally like a clock (times are from 8am to 6pm, so 12h clock would be fine).

Unfortunately I could not find a suitable command - can anyone help?

Comment: look at the `coord_polar()` function in `ggplot2` or how to make circular barplot in R

Comment: Thank you - that's what I was looking for!

Comment: Potentially useful (or a duplicate): [time display in clock with xy scatter plot in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854370/time-display-in-clock-with-xy-scatter-plot-in-r)

Comment: Potentially useful (or a duplicate): [How to draw clock in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877379/how-to-draw-clock-in-r)