# Is there an R function that converts time into an analogue display?

Tags: r, time, clock

I am analyzing a data set and I have around 20 time-points, . I want to find a good way to display  these in an analogue clock  using R or Excel. are there any r packages out there that could do this?

I tried the ggclock package , it didn't work for me. I want to make a clock that has one hand for every reading. so if 9 rabbits started eating at 9 am, and 3 rabbits started eating at 11 am, we would see a thicker hand at 9( overlapping readings) than at 11. If there is a 24hr analog clock, one diagram would suffice, but otherwise 2 different clockfaces would be needed.

Comment: I'm not aware of a package for it, but converting time to a rotation should be simple trigonometry and you can set the weight of a line based on a count.   Also check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11878078/16730940

Answer (score 0):

No particular care taken here for styling, but here's a minimal example:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(hour = c(9, 11), rabbits = c(9, 3))) +
         geom_segment(aes(x = hour %% 12, xend = hour %% 12,
                          y = 0, yend = 1, linewidth = rabbits), lineend = "round") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(12, 1:11), limits = c(0, 12), expand = c(0,0)) + 
  coord_polar()
```

[image]